# session data is not being passed around

Tags: php

Inside of my php.ini, I have session.autostart = 1

I have a few files. inside of my `connect.php` file:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$server_name = "localhost";
$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database_name = "table";

$connection = mysqli_connect($server_name, $user_name, $password,$database_name);
 
// Checking the  connection
if (!$connection) {
  die("Failed ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

inside of my login page i have the simple login form below... at the top of the page, i am including the `connect.php` which has the `session.start()`.

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["email"]);  
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["password"]);  
       $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$username'";  
       $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);  
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  {  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
                 if(password_verify($password, $row["password"])) {  
                      //return true;  
                      $_SESSION["userId"] = $row["userId"];  
                      header("location: http://localhost/dashboard/entry.php");  
                 }  
                 else {  
                      echo '<script>alert("Wrong User Details - PASSWORD DOESNT MATCH")</script>';  
                 }  
            }  
       } else {  
            echo '<script>alert("Wrong User Details - NO EMAIL")</script>';  
       }
```

now, when i successfully log in, i get taken to `entry.php`. the only thing i have in there is the following and "NO SESSION" is being printed:

```
<?php 
    include('connect.php');

     if(!isset($_SESSION["userId"])) { 
         echo "NO SESSION";
//          header("location: http://localhost/dashboard/index.php");  
     } else {
         echo "WE HAVE A SESSION!!!";
     }
?>
```

I also tested this inside of the login. instead of going into `entry.php`, I echo `$_SESSION["userId"]` after adding it into my session, and it was printing the userId from the DB.

what exactly am I doing wrong here? this is a brand new XAMPP install.

Comment: Noticed a probable bug: I'm not sure you should be mysql-escaping the password since you're not using it in a query. It could fail to verify if a user has say a quote (`"`) or apostrophe (`'`) in his/her password.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this error. Perhaps the session is not saving -- You could try throwing in a `session_write_close();` call just before the `header()` call.

Comment: Why no `session_start` in `entry.php`?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Comment: @AbraCadaver ITS IN CONNECT.PHP

Comment: _"Inside of my php.ini, I have session.autostart = 1"_ - and why do you _still_ have `session_start();` in your connect.php then?